# SIR model without ode function

Tags: r, ode

I have got following code of basic SIR model. I need the differential equation to be solved without ode() function or any other. Can you help me please how calculate this differential equations without using the ode() function?

```
library(deSolve)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Choose amounts"),

  fluidRow(column(width = 4,


  sliderInput(inputId = "time_values", label = "Days", value = 10, min = 1, max = 10),
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Disease", value = 0.05, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.05),
  sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Cure", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),
  ),
  column(width = 8,

  (plotOutput("plot"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S
      dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
      dR <-  gamma * I
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
    })
  }

  initial_values <-  c(S = 1000, I = 1, R = 0)

  sir_values_1 <- reactiveValues(val = data.frame())

  observe({
    sir_values_1$val <- as.data.frame(ode(
      y = initial_values,
      times = seq(0, input$time_values),
      func = sir_equations,
      parms = c(beta=input$beta, gamma=input$gamma) 
    ))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    with(sir_values_1$val, {
    plot(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$S, type = "l", col = "blue",
         xlab = "Days", ylab = "Number of people")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$I, col = "red")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$R, col = "green")
    legend("right", c("halthy", "infected", "cured"),
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: not sure this is a shiny question. I've never used R to solve differential equations but maybe [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html) will be useful to you

Comment: Agree that the Shiny stuff is a bit of a distraction.  Can you give a little more context? Why can't/don't you want to use `deSolve::ode()`? (You could implement [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) with a `for` loop, or some more sophisticated integrator ...)

Comment: It is an assignment into school, and we are not alowed to use any package, but to simply write the calculation on our own. Do you know how to run it with Euler´s or Runge-Kutts method?

Comment: Yes, we know how to write an Euler or RK, of course ;-) We don't know if your school would allow us to show you a full solution, but we can give you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's give you a hint. In most ode solver packages of R, all solvers are written in Fortran or C. But, I still remember that package **odesolve**, the predecessor of **deSolve**, contained a simple explicit fixed step Runge-Kutta solver "rk4.R" written in pure R.

You can go to the CRAN Archive, download the last version of **odesolve**, and see how integration was done:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/odesolve/

Then use your favorite textbook (or Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), understand the algorithm and adapt it to your needs.